# unpacking rar with R system()

Tags: regex, r, shell, system, rar

OK this task seems to be really easy to do. However I spent a couple of hours without any results.

User have:

- 7z
- Windows
- R

User should enter:

- path to 7z (z7path)
- filename

System should unpack rar into the project's root

I tried:

```
cmd = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z e D:/20140601.rar"
system(shQuote(cmd))
```

And..nothing happens.
Please don't advise to set up PATH, it doesn't help, and this should work without it.

Comment: What happens when you execute this directly from the Windows shell?

Comment: Note that this probably means that the file will be extracted in the working dir of the R session (see `getwd`), is this the directory you expect? If you want another output dir, set your working dir using `setwd`, or pass a different output location to your `system` call. In addition, 7z normally asks for a confirmation to overwrite a file, see `-y` for a way to get around that.

Comment: thx for comments, I found two curious things:
1. file downloaded via file.download is becoming damaged somehow
2. i need to specify -o output folder

Comment: first try to make the code work in a ```.bat``` file. to make sure it works. but i think in the end it will look something like ```cmd = paste("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z e D:/20140601.rar ",getwd(), sep=" ")```

Comment: any tips why downloading the rar file from url returns corrupted file? Although no warnings in the process. Downloading via hand (in browser) return nice working rar.

Comment: File download problem is a separate question. Please read the help/manual for whatever tool you're using to download the .rar file, then post a separate question if you haven't solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I finally got it.

1. Use shell
2. Use shQuote for surrounding path
3. Use right keys

   ```
   z7path = shQuote('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z')
   file = paste(getwd(), '/101-01.rar', sep = '')
   cmd = paste(z7path, ' e ', file, ' -y -o', getwd(), '/', sep='')
   shell(cmd)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify the code from the second answer, and finally it works.
You can change "-ir!*.* -o" by "-y -o" if you want all files.

```
z7path = shQuote('C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z')
file = paste('"', 'D:/20140601.rar', '"',sep = '')
cmd = paste(z7path, ' e ', file, ' -ir!*.* -o', '"', getwd(), '"', sep='')

system(cmd)
```